# How to make sed pattern "intelligent"

Tags: sed

I have a file like:

```
None44  DET20_22526;size=4; DET20_39906;size=2; DEX29.h_40767;size=4;    DEX27.h_779;size=6757;
```

Goal:

```
None44  DET20_22526 DET20_39906 DEX29.h_40767    DEX27.h_779
```

Simply remove the ";size=****;

The digits after size= range from 1-6757 (at the most).

I have been trying:

```
sed 's/;size=*;//g'
```

My limited knowledge of sed and regX limited me to this.

Can someone point out how to either remove all between ;'s including the ;'s

or

How to make my sed realize what I can state in English... but can't code yet  :(

Comment: It's not the morning on the internet ;)

Comment: Harsh bro :P  I just like to keep my post light, and it is morning (5:30am) on the day of my 12hour assay from hell! Must keep the spirits up so the molecular biology bad jew-jew stays away from my experiment.

Comment: I think you mean "bad juju", not "bad jew-jew" :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try :

```
sed 's/;size=[0-9]*;//g'
```

What does this regex means ?

- s/`...`/`...`/g stands for : replace every match of first expression with the second expression
- first expression, in our case, is `;size=[0-9]*;` that shoud be decomposed as:

  - the exact string `;size=`, followed by
  - zero or more occurences of any digit in the range `0-9`, followed by
  - `;`
- second expression is empty, so the matched part is suppressed
- the final `g` is an option that tells `sed` to match all matching parts, and not stop at the first one

Comment: - I am laughing out loud... I just found and wrote the exact same thing.  Thank you, it works fyi

Comment: Likewise, I was typing the exact same regex code when I see "A new answer has been posted". Darn!  +1